# Kivy - Error Unable permissions?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy

I need some help. I'm studying kivy and I use pycharm as IDE for development. 
To work with kivy I created a virtualenvs with requeriments:

```
kivy = 1.10
Cython = 0.23
Python = 3.5
```

As for setup I did not have too much trouble. It came later when I tried to generate a layout and it did not appear.
Is my code:

```
# coding = utf-8

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

def click():
    print (ed.text)

def build():

    layout = FloatLayout()

    ed = TextInput(text="USER.COM")
    global ed
    ed.size_hint = None, None
    ed.height = 300
    ed.width = 400
    ed.y = 60
    ed.x = 250

    bt = Button(text="Click Me")
    bt.size_hint = None, None
    bt.height = 50
    bt.width = 200
    bt.y = 150
    bt.x = 170
    bt.size_hint = None, None
    bt.on_press = click()

    layout.add_widget(ed)
    layout.add_widget(bt)

    return layout


Window.size=600,600
open= App()
open.title = "USER_FREE_AS"
open.buid=build
open.run()
```

The log reports that pycharm is not allowed to access the function. Is my log:

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/k35/bin/python /home/user/Projetos/Python/kivy/source/tela_layout/main.py
/home/user/Projetos/Python/kivy/source/tela_layout/main.py:18: SyntaxWarning: name 'ed' is assigned to before global declaration
  global ed
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/victorpenna/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-11-13_11.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 17.3.0-rc2 - padoka PPA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) '>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event8
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event8>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event13
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event13>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event14
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event14>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event8". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event13". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event14". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

P.S: My linux is ubuntu 16.04, Intel GPU.

Comment: The problem is not the permissions, but you have used a variable without having declared it: *SyntaxWarning: name 'ed' is assigned to before global declaration
  global ed*. The solution is `global ed
    ed=TextInput(text="USER.COM")`

Comment: The error still continues, I can not call the layout independent to order insert global ed

Comment: Have you tried running it from the terminal?

Comment: The error still continues, even by the terminal!

Comment: So the problem is not with PyCharm but only with kivy.

Comment: Is this really your code or did you only post a part of it? `build` should not be simply a function but you should create a new class inheriting from `App` where you override `build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
open.buid=build
```

should probably be

```
open.build=build
```

But don't do that. Putting methods to an instance afterwards (monkeypatching) gets very confusing fast. Other developers will not expect it in this situation. Also kivy does some magic with the classname of the app, it will locate the `.kv` file following a naming convention. So instead write:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):

    def click(self):
        print(self.ed.text)

    def build(self):

        layout = FloatLayout()

        self.ed = TextInput(text="USER.COM")
        ed.size_hint = None, None
        ed.height = 300
        ed.width = 400
        ed.y = 60
        ed.x = 250

        bt = Button(text="Click Me")
        bt.size_hint = None, None
        bt.height = 50
        bt.width = 200
        bt.y = 150
        bt.x = 170
        bt.size_hint = None, None
        bt.on_press = click()

        layout.add_widget(ed)
        layout.add_widget(bt)

        return layout


Window.size=600,600
open= MyApp()
open.title = "USER_FREE_AS"
open.run()
```

That way you also avoid the global variable, which is most of the time a sign that you do something suboptimal.

If you are still new to kivy I recommend going through the [kivy tutorials](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy, after really studying hours we let pass details. I'm reading the documentation to be able to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

## Dark Window

A dark window was displayed because there is a typo error.

Replace:

```
open.buid=build
```

with:

```
open.build=build
```

### Kivy Documentation

[Programming Guide » Kivy Basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html)

[Programming Guide » Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

## Device Permission

In order to use these devices, you need to grant the user or group permission. This can be done via (in your case, replace "X" with 8, 13, 14):

```
$ sudo chmod u+r /dev/input/eventX
```

## SyntaxWarning: name 'ed'

You should declare global variable ***ed*** before assignment.

```
ed = ""


def click():
    print (ed.text)


def build():
    global ed

    layout = FloatLayout()

    ed = TextInput(text="USER.COM")
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: . Thanks for the advice, I'll write it down as good practices in programming in kivy

Answer (score 0):

Change owner of `event<X>` to current user by

`sudo chown $whoami:input /dev/input/event8`

or run it as root like as

`sudo ./env/bin/python3 main.py`